# Show that $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x-\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor -\frac{1}{2}}{x^{s+1}}(1-s\log x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is convergent for $\Re s > -1$

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, special-functions

I am struggling to understand the example in [Special Functions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521789885) p. 621, that states, that 
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x-\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor -\frac{1}{2}}{x^{s+1}}(1-s\log x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
is convergent for $\Re s > -1$ by Abel's test. I do not see how it is deduced using the Abel's test when it is about the infinite series. Is it possible to show it the other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test) is enough: $\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}$ is a function with a bounded primitive and $\frac{1-s\log x}{x^{s+1}}$ is monotonically convergent to zero from some point on.

Comment: Is $\{x\}=x-\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor$? Is it correctly understood, that you can use this test when you are using the [integral test for convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence)? I mean, why use this test, when it's about the series?

Comment: @Hopeless: I am using the integral version of Dirichlet's test, and yes, $\{x\}$ stands for the fractional part of $x$, i.e. $x-\lfloor x\rfloor $.

Comment: Could you please tell me why $\frac{1-s\log x}{x^{s+1}}$ is monotonic, if $\Re s > -1$? What I did, was to find the modulus of it, and then differentiating it w.r.t. $x$, and analyzing it, to make sure that it's $<0$. But finding the modulus of it is what troubles me, especially on the numerator.

Comment: @Hopeless: that is obviously true for the function $\frac{1}{x^{s+1}}$, and the $1-s\log x$ factor is not able to alter the monotonicity from some point on: it is simply too small.